# JSF 2.0 - switching locale with h:commandLink - message bundle not in synch

Tags: jsf-2, internationalization, commandlink

In my xhtml page I have the following tag included:

```html
<f:view locale="#{languageBean.locale}">
...
</f:view>
```

I have implemented a language bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "languageBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LanguageBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -4260383661321467037L;

  ...    

  private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

  public String switchToDE() {
    LOGGER.info("switching to german");
    Locale german = Locale.GERMAN;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(german);
    this.locale = german;
    return null;
  }

  public String switchToEN() {
    LOGGER.info("switching to english");
    Locale english = Locale.ENGLISH;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(english);
    this.locale = english;
    return null;
  }

  public Locale getLocale() {
    return locale;
  }

  public void setLocale(final Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
  }

}
```

Then I want to render commandLinks to switch locale:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <h:form>
          <h:commandLink class="" action="#{languageBean.switchToDE}">Deutsch</h:commandLink>
      </h:form>
  </li>
  <li>
      <h:form>
          <h:commandLink action="#{languageBean.switchToEN}">English</h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On some places in my page I have some outputs where I render messages:

```html
#{msg['message.key.1']
```

In my faces-config.xml I have configured:

```xml
<locale-config>
  <default-locale>de</default-locale>
  <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
  <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
```

Now my problem: the first click visits the switch locale method but the message bundles are not refreshed in the page. If I click a second time on the same language the message bundle is updated. The message bundle lookup is always one step behind the locale switching.
How could I switch locale with h:commandButton tag (I need a link and the style guide disallow to use a  or ) so the message bundle lookup is in sync?

I am using GF 2.1 with Mojarra 2.0.9 (JSF 2.0 based on Servlet API 2.5).
Any advice is welcome.

EDIT:

Ok, I found out that it was my fault cause we try some "special" things ;-)

I try to explain what we have and what we try:

- we are building our software with maven
- we have separated logically different web apps for different business purposes in the SVN repo
- during build time we aggregate all web apps into one (WAR-overlay)
- therefore we have for each business purposed web app a faces-config-<business-webapp-id>.xml registered
- each web app has it's own resource bundle registered with the name "<business-webapp-id>msg"
- we have a common webapp (framework) which renders navigation items for all registered web apps
- each web has the possibility to register nav-items.
- the framework now tries to aggregate all resource bundles into one big ressource bundles during the phase where the current navigation items will be returned.

I found out that the method "getItems()" on our navigation bean is called before the switchLocale method is triggered and therefore the switching of the locale is too late.

Now I try to ask if there is the possibility to switch the locale with the h:commandLink or maybe with a h:outputLink so that the switching of the locale take place before the backing bean method for "getItems()" is triggered?

I hope that I have explained my "challenge" so that it is understandable.

Comment: In your real code, didn't you use ajax to switch the language? To exclude one and other, what if you redirect back or return non-null? (e.g. empty string)

Comment: I don't use ajax to switch the locale. And I return null cause the switching of the locale should be possible on every page and therefore I don't know the exact outcome at this moment. And how could I redirect back in a JSF backing bean?

Comment: Do `return "";` instead of `return null;` to force JSF to create a new view, or do `return viewRoot.getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";` to force JSF to send a redirect to the same view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "getViewId()" and the redirect directive did the trick for me. You saved my day!!!!

Comment: Nice. I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how and why this problem is caused. You can try the following in order to force JSF to recreate the view. Instead of returning `null` on action methods, return an empty string or force a redirect to the same view.

```
public String switchToDE() {
    // ...
    return "";
}
```

or

```
public String switchToDE() {
    // ...
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, if your environment supports EL 2.2, it would be more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) if you use a single action method for this. E.g.

```
public String switchLanguage(String language) {
    // ...
}
```

with

```
<h:commandLink action="#{languageBean.switchLanguage('EN')}">English</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As I said before the redirect and the getViewId() did the trick for me and is really sufficient. I have refactored the stuff already to a single method as you mention it here. Cause we are running in Glassfish 2.1 we cannot use the EL with the parameter therefor I added a <f:setPropertyActionListener ...> tag to populate the chosen locale first.